# Passing return value to a function called by reference

Tags: c++, return-value, pass-by-reference

I have a function that works with objects of a custom type (class).
To avoid copying that object, I want to make my function to uses it by reference.

This works fine for objects created by code, but for objects of the same type returned by a method, it doesn't.

Here is a simple example with integers, where areEqual is the function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class part
{
    int i_Nbr;
    public:
    part(int n){
        i_Nbr = n;
    }
    int getNbr(){
        return i_Nbr;
    }
};

bool areEqual(int& q1, int& q2){
    return q1==q2;
}

int main(){
    int i1 = 50;
    int i2 = 60;
    part a(240);
    part b(220);
    bool eq;

    // this works
    eq = areEqual(i1, i2 );
    cout << eq << endl;

    // but this doesn't
    eq = areEqual(a.getNbr(), b.getNbr() );
    cout << eq << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In my case objects are not integers, but are instances of a class with many internal variables and many methods.
is there a way to do this correctly ?

**UPDATE:**
by doesn't works I mean I got an compile error:

```
file.cpp:32:28: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are the two lines equivalent? Did you copy-paste and forget to change the second line? Also, can you elaborate on "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Derek : yes, you're right. sorry.

Comment: You want to use `const int&` arguments for `areEqual`. In other words, `bool areEqual(const int& q1, const int& q2)`.

Comment: To elaborate on crayzeewulf's comment, `areEqual()` takes non-`const` references as input, but non-const references cannot be initialized with temporary values, such as from function return values. You have to either make the references `const`, or else don't use references at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool eq = areEqual(a.getNbr(), b.getNbr() );
```

doesn't work since the functions return an `int`, which is a temporary object in the call to `areEqual`. A temporary object can't be used when the argument type is `int&`. Use `int const&` as argument type in `areEqual` or simply `int`.

```
bool areEqual(int const& q1, int const& q2){ ... }
```

or

```
bool areEqual(int q1, int q2){ ... }
```

Comment: Making the reference `const` prolongs the lifetime of the temporary object: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/